# System.loadLibrary() does not work but System.load() does

Tags: java

I have installed tesseract library and it is in the following path

```
[mehrdad@MHRS ocr-module]$ ldconfig -p | grep tess
    libtesseract.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libtesseract.so.3
```

but when I try to load it by any of the following I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`:

```
    System.loadLibrary("tesseract"); //error
    System.loadLibrary("libtesseract"); //error
    System.loadLibrary("libtesseract.so"); //error
    System.loadLibrary("libtesseract.so.3.0.4"); //error
```

but when I load it by `System.load()` it works:

```
    System.load("/usr/lib64/libtesseract.so.3.0.4");
```

this is the error I get (when I use `System.loadLibrary()`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libtesseract.so.3.0.4 in java.library.path: [/home/mehrdad/opencv/build/lib/, /usr/lib64/]
```

as you see the java.library.path point to the exact location of `libtesseract`.

this is weird that I can load by absolute library file path (`System.load()`) but not by `System.loadLibrary()`

what is the problem?

NOTE: I do not want to use `System.load()`, I do not want to use absolute path.

Update:
I think you can reproduce with following steps is Centos 7:

1 - `sudo yum install tesseract`

2 - run the following code :

```
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        System.load("/usr/lib64/libtesseract.so.3.0.4"); //ok
        System.loadLibrary("tesseract"); //ERROR
    }
}
```

3 - get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no tesseract in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1867)
    at com.pouya.ocrproject.ocr.App.main(App.java:9)
```

line 9 is System.loadLibrary("tesseract");

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**:

when I create a link it works!

```
[mehrdad@MHRS lib64]$ sudo ln -s libtesseract.so.3.0.4 libtesseract.so
```

Comment: Just a guess but did you try adding the full path `/usr/lib64/` to the beginning?

Comment: `loadLibrary` argument is a library name, not a path. `Directory separator should not appear in library name`

Comment: @Abra, please read the question. I tested with every possible `libname`

Comment: apparently, it has problems with version suffixes. what do the docs say about version suffixes?